# Can both image target and object target be added one single database in unity vuforia?

Tags: unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, vuforia, android-augmented-reality

I am developing an android app where I have to train my app to recognize two images and four objects.I created one single database where I added all the images and objects target in vuforia developer site and created the unity package. Now neither image nor object is getting recognized.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the problem is the same for objects and images.
I think you should share some more info about what your doing as well as some meaningful code implementing it.
W/O that, I would suggest:

1. verify that the database and trackables are loaded and active @ runtime
2. if so, see in console that the trackables are tracked by Vuforia
3. if so, verify the code enabling your augmentations

Please confirm whether have run trough these steps already and what results you got. I can share some code and further tips once the issue is a little but more specific.

Regards